# Why capacitor voltage getting low even in open circuit?

Tags: supercapacitor

I got two 2.7V 100F supercapacitors. I have wired them in series and applied 5V.

One capacitor I have tried have been about 2V. I put it on my desk without any connection.

A couple of hours later, when I measured the voltage of capacitor, it was about 0.5V.

So, energy formula of a capacitor says that it is proportional with 2nd power of capacitor voltage. In my case, voltage dropped 4 times and rate of energy loss is about 16 times.

I cannot figure out where this energy has gone.

Comment: Equivalent parallel resistance is what you want to look at.

Comment: Properly stated, the voltage has dropped to 1/4 of its initial value, therefore the stored energy has dropped to 1/16 of its initial value.  This is the total energy loss, not the rate of energy loss.

Answer (score 2):

What you are noticing is known as leakage current or self discharge. It is to be expected.  A supercap is not like a battery that uses a chemical reaction to supply electrical energy, it discharges like a capacitor does.

Here is an interesting plot from [Tecate group](http://www.tecategroup.com/ultracapacitors-supercapacitors/ultracapacitor-FAQ.php)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not really a supercapacitor in the traditional sense. A supercap will have a very low self discharge in order to replace a battery. You just have a very high capacitance capacitor that has a fairly average self discharge rate because it is designed to provide smoothing and high currents, rather than long term battery backup.

Comment: Can I find a supercapacitor in order to replace a battery? Does it provide high current too?